# Avoiding the parabolic 'bulge' when animating width and height at same time

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 elements, one with `width:75%` and the other `width:25%`. I am using pseudo elements to give these an aspect ratio.

The first element is given aspect ratio of 3:1. The second, a ratio of 1:1.

I am trying to animate this so that when hovering over the element with `width:25%`, it and it's sibling will switch widths and aspect ratios, essentially making the one grow to 75% and the other shrink to 25%.

However, when doing this, though the animation is smooth, as they animate, they 'bulge', growing in height before eventually coming to rest at their switched sizes. What it SHOULD look like is just as if the widths of the 2 elements changed. This may not make sense; see for yourself in this fiddle:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jrdcr62/)
(hover over the yellow square. If it and the red rectangle are not beside each other, widen the frame a little — it uses bootstrap)

Of course, a simple solution would be to set the height rather than use ratios. But that wont work with the responsive grid I'm using. So it must use the pseudo-element aspect ratios.

I'm sure this isn't a bug in the code or anything obviously — it's behaving exactly as it's supposed to. But I'm trying to figure out how to counteract the 'bulge' I thought maybe giving both elements an easing that was inverse of the other might fix it, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: use mouseover event https://jsfiddle.net/2jrdcr62/1/

Comment: @madalinivascu Sorry, that doesn't fix it. The problem I'm trying to fix is the height of the two divs growing and then shrinking when they switch sides, rather than just the width.